# download a url file with javascript istead of opening the file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to download a file from the server using javascript/jquery.

When press the button the server response with an url file that i want to download.

the button:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="exportInvoice">Export XML</a>
```

the ajax request:

```
$('#exportInvoice').on('click', function () {                
     $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           url: '{{ route('export-xml') }}',
           data: {dateRange: dateRange},
           success: function (resp) {                        
                if(resp.error){
                    // error
                    alert(resp.msg);
                } else {
                    // success
                    alert(resp.msg);
                    window.location=resp.url;
                }
            }
       });
})
```

I am using laravel 5.7 blade to generate the url.

When i click the button the file will open instead of download (because of the window.location=resp.url;

I was thinking... after the ajax call is made (when success response).... setting the download attribute and href to the link.... but then i need to call again the click event to download the file.

How can i download the file istead of opening???

Comment: AJAX is a _background_ request, you can not directly trigger a download dialog from there. There are some workarounds, but in a case like this it might make more sense not to use AJAX to begin with. If you need to submit POST data to the server for it to generate this download resource, then you can do that by submitting a hidden form using JS.

Comment: thx @misorude for the info ;)  (using a hidden form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creating a hidden form for download the file works:

The hidden form:

```
<form id="downloadXmlForm" method="post" action="{{ route('download-xml-invoices') }}" style="display: none">
     <input type="hidden" name="xmlFileName">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Export XML</button>
     ({ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

After receiving from ajax request (on success) => submit the form to download the file:

```
$('input[name="xmlFileName"]').val(resp.fileName);                                
document.getElementById('downloadXmlForm').submit();
```

On the backend the response for the ajax request is:

```
...
$fileName = uniqid().'.xml';
$xmlFilePath = storage_path('invoices/'.$fileName);
file_put_contents($xmlFilePath, $xmlString);

return response()->json(['error' => false, 'msg' => $message, 'fileName' => $fileName]);
```

The download function that is call on form submit:

```
public function downloadInvoicesXml(Request $request){
    return response()->download( storage_path('invoices/'.$request->input('xmlFileName')));
}
```

If anyone have any better idea, please tell me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
window.location.href = resp.url
```

This will start the download in the same page, exactly like when you click a link without any target other than `_self`.

Comment: i have already tried that...the same effect (will open the file)

Comment: To force the download of a file, make sure you send the right headers with it:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf";

This will make sure that the file is not displayed in the browser instead of being downloaded. Replace the filename part with the filename you want as default on the save as dialog.